# Preview Image is not working in Gmail annotation email

Tags: json, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud, type-promotion, gmail-promo-tab

I was expecting image in the annotation preview in my promotional email which I am creating in SFMC. I am getting the email in promotion inbox but the promotional image is not coming in preview, can someone check and let me know what's wrong with below code that I put in body tag.

```
%%[
     SET @JSONStart = Concat('<', 'script type="',' application/ld+json"','>')
     SET @JSONEnd = Concat('<','/','script','>')
     ]%%
     %%=TreatAsContent(@JSONStart)=%%
     [{
     "@context": "http://schema.org/",
     "@type": "Organization",
     "logo": "https://image.e.iqos.com/lib/fe3f15707564067e701170/m/1/13d0f5ae-82cf-4c45-ac62-d2733594acef.png"
     },
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "subjectLine": "recomendar tiene premio"
  },
   
  {
     "@context": "http://schema.org/",
     "@type": "DiscountOffer",
 "description": "PHP1000 OFF",
    "discountCode": "IQOS1000",
"availabilityStarts": "2023-11-30T00:00:00+0800",
    "availabilityEnds":"2023-12-15T00:00:00+0800"
     },
 {`your text`
     "@context": "http://schema.org/",
     "@type": "PromotionCard",
     "image": "https://image.e.iqos.com/lib/fe3f15707564067e701170/m/1/e8de2a82-6fa4-4b6a-9584-6b658dc066f0.png"
     }]
     %%=TreatAsContent(@JSONEnd)=%%
```